# Why do I get an error with the json original codes?

Tags: python, json, error-handling

How to fix this error?
I have a very long code, within which I am using:

```
import json

folder = json.loads(file_content[0][:-1])
```

and

```
 f.write(json.dumps(saveable_folder))
```

from json library. However, I get the following error:

```
File"C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\envs\virtualenvironment\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\envs\virtualenvironment\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\envs\virtualenvironment\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
        obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 85 (char 84)
```

Is it because I need to change something in json library? or because I have a virtual environment in Anaconda, but I am using VScode?
I am completely lost.
Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is, that `file_content[0][:-1]` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any hints how to fix this?